# How to set value to deep depth of Dictionary?

Tags: swift, swift5

I use Swift.
I have a dictionary variable.
The dictionary looks like JSON structure.
So, key:value type is [String: AnyObject].
I want to set a value in deep depth of the dictionary.

```
var dic1: [String: AnyObject] = [String: AnyObject]()
```

And, if print dic1, show below.

```
{
"a-1": 1,
"a-2": "a-2-1,
"a-3": [
        {
            "b-1": "hi",
            "b-2": 10,
            "b-3": [
                {
                    "c-1": 100
                },
                {
                    "c-1": 101,
                    "c-2": "aaa"
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            "b-1": "hello",
            "b-2": 20,
            "b-3": [
                {
                    "c-1": 200
                },
                {
                    "c-1": 201,
                    "c-2": "bbb"
                }
            ]
            // <- want to set to here
        }
    ]
}
```

Then, I want to set some value to key "b-4".
I tried like below but, xcode throws me "Cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'AnyObject'" error.

```
((dic1["a-3"] as? [[String: AnyObject]])?[1] as? [String: AnyObject])?["b-4"] = blahblah as AnyObject
```

Comment: You are approaching the problem wrongly. Instead of trying to represent the JSON as `[String: AnyObject]`. Write a custom struct/class that represents the JSON. Then you can set any value very easily.

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, I know the approach. But I want to solve this problem without using custom struct/class. Just, solve only use dictionary. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: I found this link. https://talk.objc.io/episodes/S01E31-mutating-untyped-dictionaries

Comment: So you found your own answer! Feel free to post an answer to your own question :)

Answer (score 0):

The error message says, you're trying to change an immutable object, which is not possible. Because in Swift, a Dictionary is a value type.

First get the object you want to to modify to a variable, and assign back after modification. Smth like below:

```
var a3 = (dic1["a-3"] as? [[String: AnyObject]])
a3?[1]["b-4"] = blahblah as AnyObject
dic1["a-3"] = a3 as AnyObject
```